# Openmp find number of threads available on machine

Tags: fortran, openmp

I'm running parallelized computations on my computer. I'd like the program not to use all the cores, but leave one free for the system.
How can I set the number of threads in program to one less than there are on processor?

The `OMP_get_max_threads()`, `OMP_set_num_threads` pair doesn't solve this for me: I've compiled the program into octave function (oct-file) and invoke it via octave interpreter. `OMP_get_max_threads()` obtains the environmental variable or something, thus, this variable is kept between calls and subsequent calls to the calculation routine decrease the value further. First call uses 3 cores, second - 2, and so on.

So, how does one determines the hardware available number of threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `OMP_GET_NUM_PROCS()` to get the available cpu cores (logical or physical, hyper-threading can play a role).

`OMP_get_max_threads()` usually returns the same number. I don't get your description of it decreasing, perhaps you should show some example.

See also https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/302866

Comment: Well, that was caused by me using the programm inside octave interpreter. Using `OMP_GET_NUM_PROCS()` solved it.